# onSensorChanged and Threads, Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I´m working with sensor accelerometer and i wonder if it´s possible and how to run two things in onSensorChanged.
1. i want to Accelerometer data x,y,z allways store in the field 
2. if shake is detect, run another activity

My question is, when shake is detect and run another activity, i still want to store x,y,z in my fields. How can i do that?

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x = values[0];
    y = values[1];
    z = values[2];
    ....
 ThreadForLoopA threatA = new ThreadForLoopA(x,y,z);
 ThreadForLoopB threatB = new ThreadForLoopB();
   ....
  threatA.run();
  threatB.run();
```

X,y,z are changing all the time and i get just the first x,y,z data in my threadA class.

Is possible to create threads inside onSensorChanged? Hope someone understant what i´m trying to do :)  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thread is started with `start`, not `run`. `run` will just call the method sequentially on the main thread.